# Popup to Parent Window Communication in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, iframe

I have an iframe embedded into a legacy application.  Inside of the iframe I need to do oauth (I'm capturing authentication tokens for later use).  In order to do oauth from within an iframe I need to use a popup window.  What I need is for that popup window to communicate back to the iframe when oauth completes so the page within the iframe can refresh its data.  I need to support IE 10+, Chrome, and Firefox, and everything I've tried works fine in Chrome/Firefox but fails in IE.  My current solution (which almost works) looks like this:

```
/** From within the iframe **/
var storageName = 'SoProOauth';
var addAccountDeferred;
$window.addEventListener('storage', function (evt) {
    if (evt.key == storageName) {
        localStorage.removeItem(storageName);
        getAccounts().then(function () {
            addAccountDeferred.resolve();
        });
    }
});

// ... later ...
addAccount: function (type) {
    addAccountDeferred = $q.defer();
    var uri = util.format('/oauth/%s/connect?auth=%s&return_uri=%s',
              type, configuration.get('auth'), encodeURI('/configure/oauthcomplete'));

    if (Boolean(configuration.get('debug'))) {
        uri += '&debug=true';
    }

    localStorage.removeItem(storageName);
    var oauthWindow = $window.open(uri, 'oauth', 'width=800,height=600');
    if (oauthWindow && oauthWindow.focus) oauthWindow.focus();

    return addAccountDeferred.promise;
}

/** From within the popup **/
localStorage.setItem('SoProOauth', 'done');
$timeout(function () {
    setInfo('This window can be closed');
    $window.open('', '_self', '');
    $window.close();
}, 500);
```

Basically, I'm writing to local storage from within the popup window, and listening for the write event in the parent window.  This *almost* works - it works great in my local test environment but fails when I deploy it to the dev cluster.  There could be two reasons why it fails: 1) when I run locally everything is over HTTP, but in the dev cluster it is over HTTPS (worse, the page that hosts the iframe is HTTP but the iframe contents are HTTPS), or 2) when I run locally everything is localhost, but in the dev cluster the iframe host is one machine (local intranet) and the contents of the iframe are public internet (AWS).

Other things I've tried: cookies (same result - works locally but fails deployed), and all of the window properties (window.opener, window.parent, and testing for window.closed() from within the iframe) - these don't work in IE as things get reset once the domain changes (which happens because we're doing oauth).

As you can see the UI code is AngularJS, but what you can't see is it is hosted by Node.js.  So I've considered using something like socket.io but it seems so heavy-hitting - I really just need to send a quick event from the popup to the parent within the iframe.  Any thoughts?